# Lisp recursion confusion

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp, tail-recursion

I believe this to be implementation independent, but I use clisp on debian.
Below I defined two functions named `SUM`. They find the sum of two nonnegative integers by adding 1 to N2 and subtracting 1 from N1 until N1 is 0. Approach #1 makes sense to me, but approach #2 is a source of confusion.

```
;;;Approach #1 (I understand why it works)
> (defun sum (n1 n2) "Return the sum of two nonnegative integers."
      (if (zerop n1) n2 (sum (1- n1) (1+ n2)))) ;1+ adds 1 to it's operator
> (sum 5 10)
1. Trace: (SUM '5 '10)
2. Trace: (SUM '4 '11)
3. Trace: (SUM '3 '12)
4. Trace: (SUM '2 '13)
5. Trace: (SUM '1 '14)
6. Trace: (SUM '0 '15)
6. Trace: SUM ==> 15
5. Trace: SUM ==> 15
4. Trace: SUM ==> 15
3. Trace: SUM ==> 15
2. Trace: SUM ==> 15
1. Trace: SUM ==> 15
15 ;;;The result
```

This same result can be found using this other approach, which I do not understand but appears to be more common:

```
> (defun sum (n1 n2) "Return the sum of two nonnegative numbers."
    (if (zerop n1) n2 (1+ (sum2 (1- n1) n2))))
> (sum 5 10)
1. Trace: (SUM '5 '10)
2. Trace: (SUM '4 '10)
3. Trace: (SUM '3 '10)
4. Trace: (SUM '2 '10)
5. Trace: (SUM '1 '10)
6. Trace: (SUM '0 '10)
6. Trace: SUM ==> 10
5. Trace: SUM ==> 11
4. Trace: SUM ==> 12
3. Trace: SUM ==> 13
2. Trace: SUM ==> 14
1. Trace: SUM ==> 15
15
```

It can be clearly seen that these do **something very different** and get the same result. How does lisp allow for the behavior in the second approach, and what is the function `+1` acting on in the second approach by adding 1 to a function, as a function is not a variable?
I got these two functions from chapter 15 of *["COMMON LISP: An Interactive Approach"](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~shapiro/Commonlisp/)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum2` isn't that different.  Both take 1 from `n1`; the first `sum` moves it to `n2`, while the second adds it to the result of the recursive call.

The nice thing about the first `sum` is that it is *tail recursive*: it returns just the result of the recursive call, which can be implemented a lot more efficiently (and more closely models a loop).

Comment: I believe I have better stated the problem in an edit to allow for the type of answer I am looking for, please have a look at the last few sentences as I have changed them.

Comment: How exactly can it perform 1+ to a recursive call?

Comment: '1+', as its name suggests, returns 1 more than its argument; in this case, we are adding 1 to the *result returned* by the recursive call.  (I assume 'sum2' is a typo.)

Comment: I understand now, the above comment explained what I needed. Thanks.^